# Cisco CGS2520 switch to reveal MAC address when port goes active?

Tags: cisco, syslog

Is there a way to have a Cisco switch reveal the MAC address of a device via Syslog when it is plugged in?

I get messages that a device is connected, but there isn't a lot of detail:

```
Sep  9 12:50:51 10.9.8.7 6531: *Sep  9 12:47:50: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to up
Sep  9 12:50:51 10.9.8.7 6532: *Sep  9 12:47:51: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to up
```

The hope is that if unrecognized devices are plugged into the network, we can be notified at the switch level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't work, because the switch will learn which MAC address is on the other end of a connection only when some traffic starts flowing through it; plugging in the cable just isn't enough. This will very likely happen in a few seconds, but it doesn't happen *at the same time*, thus the switch doesn't have any way to know and report this information when a link goes up.

Besides, there could be many more than a single address on the other end, if the cable goes to another switch; there could even not be any address at all, if there's a switch on the other end but there is nothing else plugged into it.

The only way to gather this information is to have a look at the MAC address table, and only after the switch has had enough time to learn what is connected to it.

Comment: Very clear answer.   I'll have to consider how to use the MAC table for this kind of function.  Thanks.